# How to exact match the lock screen picture with the start screen picture?

Tags: lumia-640

- Model: MS Lumia 640 LTE
- Screen resolution: 720x1280
- Problem: Selecting the same picture (720x1280) for both lock screen and start screen, the start one will look a bit fuzzy because the picture is automatically enlarged for panning.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to open the picture, take a phone print screen, and use this printed picture as lock screen and start screen.

My phone is a Lumia 640 XL.

Comment: I resized the original to 600x1066 and added space to the right and bottom back to 720x1280 and now they look like twins on screen.